# Temporary HP on missed attack

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Let's say I attack with a power that gives me Temporary HP like Bolstering Strike (Paladin). Do I still get the THP even if I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on *where* the THP are granted in the power. If you miss then:

- If the power grants them as part of the Hit line, then no, you don't get them.
- If the power grants them as part of the Effect line, then yes, you get them.
- If the power grants them as part of the Miss line, then yes you get them.

For Bolstering Strike specifically, the THP are part of the Hit line so you only get them if you hit.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly as I thought, just wanted confirmation on this one.